# Should this question be closed or left open?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, vote-to-close, close-reasons

Question link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18924687/r-randomforest-windows-mac-dosnow-domc-classes-must-be-at-least-2-error

Note that he seems to indicate he is willing to "reach an agreement" if there is any "requirement". Maybe is trying to hire someone... :-)

Is this a close case? Why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should be closed, because:

- It's unclear what's being asked.
- It *appears* to be soliciting folks to test some software rather than asking for help with a programming problem.
- It doesn't include any concrete details about the problem being encountered (if there is one).

Any one of these would be problematic; the combination is just really bad. The asker needs to sit down and focus on solving one problem at a time. Also, he might need a Mac.

Comment: Migrate to getamac.stackexchange.com? :-)

Answer (score 3):

IMO, it should be closed.

Why? He's not *asking* anything. Here's the text of the question:

> I am new to R so sorry if its something obvious. I've got this R code which is meant to be run with MAC because of parallelization package. I tried to change from doMC to doSNOW but it didn't run properly.
>
> - Could you please try it with MAC and see if the code is working?
> - Could you please try out the Windows version I've attempted to convert
> - If possible please make it work in Windows because I don't own a Mac =(
>
> The link is [here], in my shared dropbox.

It should be closed for these reasons:

- It's unclear - no code is provided, and there's no specific issue to look for
- It's asking for testing, not for help with a specific problem
- Even if testing were OK here (it's not), there still isn't a specific issue to look for - it 'just doesn't run properly'.
- The 'if possible please make it work in' is simply wrong. It should be closed as Too Broad just for this.